# Django form field required conditionally

Tags: django, forms

I'd like to have a field which is required conditionally based on setting a boolean value to `True` or `False`.

What should I return to set `required =True` if `is_company` is set to `True`?

```
class SignupFormExtra(SignupForm):
    is_company = fields.BooleanField(label=(u"Is company?"), 
                                     required=False)
    NIP = forms.PLNIPField(label=(u'NIP'), required=False)

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data.get('is_company', True):
            return ...?
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Check the Chapter on [Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) in the documentation.

The example given in the documentation can be easily adapted to your scenario:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(SignupFormExtra, self).clean()
    is_company = cleaned_data.get("is_company")
    nip = cleaned_data.get("NIP")
    if is_company and not nip:
        raise forms.ValidationError("NIP is a required field.")
    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: The link @arie provided also covers how to associate the error with the field by replacing the raise statement with

self._errors["NIP"] = self.error_class(["This is a required field."])

Comment: @Seth thanks for the comment! That was really helpful!