# Django models, How to make two optional fields, but when one is filled, the other one must also be filled

Tags: django, django-models

So, I have created a model which has some attributes, but I want to focus on these two.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    RANK_OPTIONS = (
        ('A', 'A'),
        ('B', 'B'),
    )
    related_office = models.ForeignKey('OtherModule.office', 
        related_name='office',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    rank = models.CharField(('rank'),max_length=1, choices=RANK_OPTIONS)
```

Basically, I need these two attributes to be optional, but the moment the attribute "Rank" is filled, then the attribute related_office must also be filled.
You can have a related_office and not a Rank, but the moment you have a Rank, you also need a related Office.

how can I do that?

Comment: This might help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint

Comment: This might be useful too: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just override the `clean` method in your model.py:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.rank and not self.related_office:
        raise forms.ValidationError({'related_office':["related_office is required!"]})
```

Comment: I managed to do exactly what I wanted with this solution, but using "forms.ValidationError" insteadof ValueError

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce such condition by overriding the `save` method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.rank and not self.related_office:
        raise ValueError("related_office is required!")
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It gives me an exception when I try to create one Profile, but I would like it to be, some kind of validation check, not something big error screen that kicks me out of the form

Comment: So if you want that to be as **form validation**, you need to override the `clean` method and check the condition there; check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10967900/9733868)

Answer (score 1):

I would not do this in admin save method. If its in your admin, write a ModelForm and pass it to your admin class, like this:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = "__all__"

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        if cleaned_data.get("rank") and not cleaned_data.get("related_office"):
            raise ValidationError('You have to select your related office for your rank')

        return cleaned_data
```

and reference that form in your admin class:

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProfileForm
```

If you have your custom html template, either validate it in frontend, or in backend. Just like in the example above

Comment: I get an error saying "Profile has no attribute cleaned_data"

Comment: Also I need an "exclude" attribute and a "fields" attribute to create a modelForm

Comment: I've edited my answer. There is no need to add exclude, if you do not want to exclude anything. You can type `fields = "__all__"` this will tell django to include all fields. I forgot to type in `super()` in `clean` method.